# How can i see list of powered devices in my laptop?

Tags: linux, power-management

I want to see all powered devices. I know about powertop. But that can't recognize device that isn't truly used. For example, my networkmanager is badly configured and wifi is powered on, i don't use it, but powertop doesn't show that.

So i want to see all things that can be powered off without matter of usage.

Answer (score 1):

By 'all powered devices', I'm going to assume you mean a laptop, since any unused USB device can be unplugged.  As far as I know, the only way you can query the status of your wifi directly would be to use a command like iwconfig. You can use iwconfig to turn off the wifi power, too, which you could automate via /etc/rc.local or a shortcut to toggle the state on the desktop.

Comment: I mean something like program that knowns about all devices that can be powered off, e.g. bluetooth, wifi, ethernet adapter, discrete VGA, ...